# Biber+biblatex automatic standard abbreviations

Tags: biblatex, biber, ieee-style

Is it there a way to automatically substitute IEEE standard abbreviations automatically using `biblatex + biber` (once provided a list of the abbreviations somehow)?

For example:

"Conference Record IEEE International Conference on Communication"

should become

"Conf. Rec. 1995 IEEE Int. Conf. Commun."

Comment: My first impression says the use of `@string`s in your bib file would be a good approach. But that would not be quite "automatic". `biblatex` offers dynamic modification of data with `\DeclareSourcemap`, which could be used for the purpose, I believe. But we would need you to be more specific, ideally by providing a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) which illustrates your problem and what you are trying to achieve precisely.

Comment: Has the provided answer solved your problem? If so, we kindly ask you to mark the answer as accepted. It will raise the quality of this website and help others with the same kind of problem find a solution faster. If your problem has not been solved by the provided answer, adding more details to your question might produce a more fitting answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really into the IEEE style, but I think I get your general setting, and will give it a try.

I'm supposing you are using `biblatex`'s `ieee` style, but loading `IEEEabrv.bib` provided by `IEEEtran` (even though I didn't find there the "Conference Record IEEE International Conference on Communication", so I use here an entry from `IEEEexample.bib`).

I see two ways for you to override the standard IEEE abreviations provided in `IEEEabrv.bib`. The first is for you to create a second file of abbreviation strings and load it *after* `IEEEabrv.bib`. The second is to use `biblatex`'s `\DeclareSourcemap` to change your entry's data.

The first one would go like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IEEEexample:article_typical,
  author        = "S. Zhang and C. Zhu and J. K. O. Sin and P. K. T. Mok",
  title         = "A Novel Ultrathin Elevated Channel Low-temperature 
                   Poly-{Si} {TFT}",
  journal       = IEEE_J_EDL,
  volume        = "20",
  month         = nov,
  year          = "1999",
  pages         = "569-571"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}
\addbibresource{myIEEEabrv.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Where `myIEEEabrv.bib` contains the redefinitions of the abbreviated strings you want. In this case, something like:

```
@STRING{IEEE_J_EDL        = "{IEEE} Elec. Dev. Lett."}
```

(The string defined in `IEEEabrv.bib` is `{IEEE} Electron Device Lett.`).
Notice it must be loaded after `IEEEabrv.bib`.

If I misread your question, and what you actually want is to provide some abbreviated journal titles of your own, this method also gives you a sensible approach. You can create a file `abbrev.bib`, define the strings you want there, and add it with `\addbibresource`. Then in your references `.bib` file you use the string *name* (that is, without brackets, as in the example above) in the `journaltitle`/`journal` field. You could have then:

```
@string{IEEEIntConfCom = "Conf. Rec. 1995 {IEEE} Int. Conf. Commun."}
```

and then you would use in your bibfile:

```
journaltitle = IEEEIntConfCom,
```

Usually this approach entails also having a second file where the full strings are defined, let's say `full.bib`. In it you would have:

```
@string{IEEEIntConfCom = "Conference Record {IEEE} International Conference on Communication"}
```

With it, all you have to do to change from abbreviated journals to full journal titles would be to substitute `\addbibresource{abbrev.bib}` with `\addbibresource{full.bib}` in your main `.tex` file.

The second approach, as mentioned, would be to use `\DeclareSourcemap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{IEEEexample:article_typical,
  author        = "S. Zhang and C. Zhu and J. K. O. Sin and P. K. T. Mok",
  title         = "A Novel Ultrathin Elevated Channel Low-temperature 
                   Poly-{Si} {TFT}",
  journal       = IEEE_J_EDL,
  volume        = "20",
  month         = nov,
  year          = "1999",
  pages         = "569-571"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{IEEEabrv.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=journal,
                      match={{IEEE} Electron Device Lett.},
                      replace={{IEEE} Elec. Dev. Lett.}]
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Notice the `match` is for the standard abbreviated form defined in `IEEEabrv.bib` and not for the string's name.

Obs.: I had some trouble with `IEEEabrv.bib`'s encoding. So for this to work, I needed to save it in UTF-8 to run. But I suppose that, once you seem to already be using these abbreviations, you somehow handled that.

Comment: The first one seems a good solution, I'll give it a try. Thanks.